# Applet using CardLayout is blank

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I have spent so many hours trying to research the problem with my code but I just cannot seem to find it. I have no experience using CardLayout, but based on other instances I feel I have implemented it correctly. I am developing a 2d game using custom panels that extend JPanel. I know my panels work because I have tested them separately in other driver applets. Every time I run my Applet, the screen is totally blank. I am perplexed at why this would be. I get no errors or warnings upon compiling.

Here is the code for my applet, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
    public class DodgeDefender extends JApplet
    {
        private final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
        private JPanel cardPanel;
        private IntroScreen intro;
        private MainGame main;
        private CardLayout manager;

        public void init()
        {
               setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

               cardPanel = new JPanel();
               manager = new CardLayout();
               cardPanel.setLayout(manager);

               intro = new IntroScreen();
               main = new MainGame();

               cardPanel.add(intro, "IntroScreen");
               cardPanel.add(main, "MainGame");

               manager.show(cardPanel, "IntroScreen");

        }

        public void mainGame()
        {
               manager.show(cardPanel, "MainGame");
        }

   }
```

Comment: WHat is inside MainGame and IntroScreen, maby the probem in these classes

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You don't add the cardPanel to the applet, so it doesn't have any child component to display:

```
this.add(cardPanel);
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. Unfortunately that did not fix my problem. In fact, I event added:

        getContentPane().add(cardPanel);

And that didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Then post an SSCCE so that we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part :-

```
cardPanel.add(intro, "IntroScreen");
cardPanel.add(main, "MainGame");
```

You should try this instead:-

```
add(intro,"IntroScreen");
add(main,"MainGame");
```